# JavaScript Multiple ways to call a function

Tags: javascript, function

> Write a single JavaScript function that will calculate a + b. The
>   function has to be able to be called in two different ways:
>
> ```
> calculate(a, b);
>
> calculate(a)(b);
> ```

Comment: Have you tried to answer this interview question? Did you run into a problem doing so? This isn't just an answer factory.

Comment: Is this homework? It smells like homework. You should do your own homework.

Comment: hint: Look at the function's __arguments__.

Comment: Please review the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) documentation before posting. Per the linked page: _"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."_

Comment: Questions about currying have been asked before and you are welcome to search for it here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is outside of the scope of on-topic question as set forth by the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) documentation.

Comment: No, this was an interview question. I tried looking up the answer but I never came across a function that is called this way "calculate(a)(b);"

Comment: What is your question about it? As it stands you are just citing some instructions.

Comment: *" I never came across a function that is called this way "calculate(a)(b);""* Here you go: https://lodash.com/docs#property

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Below is the code that I came up with to solve this naively. Please feel free to ask questions as to why it works or what could be done to improve it.

```
var calculate = function () {
    var arg1 = arguments[0];
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        return arg1 + arguments[1];
    }
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        return function (secondNum) {
            return secondNum + arg1;
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, there are a few concepts at work in this function. The arguments array is available inside any JavaScript function. It allows you to examine all the arguments that were passed into the function. As you can see, I first check if we have 2 arguments, that clues me in to the fact that I should add them together.

In the second case, I only got one argument, so I'll return a function that will help me accomplish the function(x)(y) case.

Comment: Really? You should not encourage these kind of questions by answering them.

Comment: Didn't realize. There's a guy asking for help so I wanted to help him.

Comment: He didn't even ask a question. How do you know which "help" he needs?

Comment: I guess technically you're correct ^__^

If there's a tag for interview-question, then i don't really see a problem with this. I guess there's a debate to be had.

Don't really want to get into a huge flame war, but to me this is a great jumping off point to start talking about the arguments array as well as currying. How can you ask a question about currying if you've never heard of the term before?

Comment: @DJKempner that `interview-question` tag should be deleted ([Reason](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/))

Comment: I'm not saying that it's wrong to "ask" this question (still don't know what the question is) in general. Just not here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's not a homework question. It was an interview questions and I was told that everyone that was interviewed had problems with it or wasn't able to answer it.

Comment: @DJKempner Looks like this topic has come up before: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256592/is-interview-question-really-a-good-tag-for-so

Comment: I've added some explanation below the code snippet. Do you have any further questions to clarify what's happening?

Comment: @War10ck hehe I could have guessed that there'd be a meta post about it. I'm actually a little curious now, what's the perceived harm in allowing "this type of question" on Stack Overflow? Who is harmed? Moderators?